# Ho to properly pass a method in a child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a child component called **goback.vue** which only function is to go back one step in the navigation history. The reason why I am asking this question is because I am trying to reuse this component often in many other components and I want to be able to edit the style and template later on just one place.

This is the code of the component **goback.vue**:

```
<template>
    <span @click="backOneStep">
       <svg type="submit" class="arrowleft" >
          <use href="../static/icons/iconsset.svg#arrowleft"></use>
       </svg>
    </span> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'goback',
    data () {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        backOneStep(){
        window.history.go(-1)
        },
    } 
}     
<script>
```

Then on my several of my **parent components** I am importing the child component in the following manner:

```
<template>
  <div class="building">
    <div id="title">
      <goback></goback> // using the child component here
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import goback from './goback.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    goback
  },
  name: 'maincomponent',
  data () {
    return {  
      }
    }
  },
  methods: { 
     backOneStep(){ // do I need to repeat this here?
      window.history.go(-1) 
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

First, I am wondering if I need to repeat the method on all parent components or if I can just write it on my child component.
Second, I am getting an error message:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "backOneStep" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in

```
 <Goback> at src/components/goback.vue
   <Depts> at src/components/depts.vue
     <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

*Note: I have carefully read the link but I am still stuck*

Immediately following the previous error message I am also getting this error message:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined
>
> found in

```
 <Goback> at src/components/goback.vue
   <Depts> at src/components/depts.vue
     <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Would be able to tell me what I can do to avoid this?
Is this related to props? I have tried declaring the "backOneStep" prop in the data of the **goback.vue** but I am not sure I have done it correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `$emit` event to tell the parent to "go back" on click in the child component:

```
<template>
  <span @click="backOneStep">
    <svg type="submit" class="arrowleft" >
      <use href="../static/icons/iconsset.svg#arrowleft"></use>
    </svg>
  </span> 
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'goback',
    methods: {
      backOneStep() {
        this.$emit('back')
      }
    } 
  }     
</script>
```

And in the parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="building">
    <div id="title">
      <goback @back="window.history.go(-1)"></goback>
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @sovalina but it didn't work. I get exactly the same error messages as soon as I render the parent component.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho which one ?

Comment: both error messages when i render the parent component :/

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property or method "backOneStep" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

 <Goback> at src/components/goback.vue
   <Depts> at src/components/depts.vue
     <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
&&
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

found in etc....

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me as the main reason I wanted to isolate this element/function on a component was to be able to change the style of the element in one place:

The child component:

```
<template>
    <span v-on:click="$emit('back')">
        <svg type="submit" class="arrowleft" >
        <use href="../static/icons/iconsset.svg#arrowleft"></use>
        </svg>
      </span> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'goback',
    data () {
        return {

        }
    } 
}     
<script>
<style scoped>
     //  enter styles here
</style>
```

On the parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="building">
    <div id="title">
      <goback @back="window.history.go(-1)"></goback>
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import goback from './goback.vue';    
export default {
  components: {
    goback
  },
  methods: {
    backOneStep(){
      window.history.go(-1)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```